# How to pass jvm arg -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to Ant task "get"

Tags: java, ant, get

I need to pass jvm arg -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to Ant task"get". 
Is it possible?

```
    <!-- getting  submit.jar  -->
    <echo message="getting  submit.jar..." />
    <get src="http://servername/Bootstrap?artifact=submit.jar" dest="../lib/submit.jar"/>
```

Initial problem is [Weird java.net.SocketException Permission Denied connect error when running Groovy in Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360913/weird-java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-connect-error-when-running-groo)

Comment: Why don't you try it? Or: What have you tried?

Comment: How? target "get" doesn't have "<jvmargs></jvmarg>"

Comment: Then ask: How to do this, and not: is it possible.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting ANT_OPTS variable. Here is an example:

```
export ANT_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

[Maven documentation (section Manual JVM options)](http://ant.apache.org/manual/proxy.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments to ant by using the `-D` argument

Try:

```
ant -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true get
```

unless a new jvm is launched while executing target `get`, your arguments will apply to commands executed for that target as well

Comment: I get java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect, when argument doesn't be applied

Comment: @skydreamerr - can update your question with (at least the relevant portions of) the build.xml? Also, do you have the same exception when calling without the parameter specified.  Also, plese post the whole stack trace for the exception

Comment: @skydreamerr - please rephrase that.  It does not make sense.

Comment: I've attached initial problem

Comment: @skydreamerr - it seems like the Windows firewall might be [the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473518/workaround-for-apache-ant-install-bug/10473581#10473581).  The link provides a solution for ftp trafic, but you could try disabling the firewall altogether while you are running the get target.  If that helps, you will need to find the right protocol to disable filtering for in the firewall, so you are not completely unprotected

Comment: I use VPN, that doesn't support ipv6